# ObjectBox does not keep previous values after type migration

Tags: android, objectbox, objectbox-java, objectbox-android, greenrobot-objectbox

We had to migrate one of the field-params in an entity from `long` to `BigDecimal`. Migration is quite smooth but there is a problem; we want to keep previous values to be set to the migrated field. But as soon as `ObjectBox` is initialized it defaults migrated field to the default value of the current type, in our case, to `null`.

Say we had:

| Id (long) | Name |
| --- | --- |
| 123 | Random Name |

After migration we got:

| Id (String) | Name |
| --- | --- |
| null | Random Name |

Is there any possible way to migrate without losing values on migrated fields?

**A side note:** I have used a converter to keep the `BigDecimal` values since `ObjectBox` doesn't support `BigDecimal`

**Converter** class:

```
public class BigIntegerStringConverter implements PropertyConverter<BigInteger, String> {
    @Override
    public BigInteger convertToEntityProperty(String databaseValue) {
        return databaseValue == null ? null : new BigInteger(databaseValue);
    }

    @Override
    public String convertToDatabaseValue(BigInteger entityProperty) {
        return String.valueOf(entityProperty);
    }
}
```

**Usage:**

```
@Convert(converter = BigIntegerStringConverter.class, dbType = String.class)
@Uid(XXXXXXXX)
BigInteger tigerId;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, **type migration where old data is kept** is not supported in ObjectBox.

Reference: https://github.com/objectbox/objectbox-java/issues/971

Answer (score 1):

> ObjectBox does not support migrating existing property data to a new type.  You will have to take care of this yourself, e.g. by keeping the old property and adding some migration logic.

Source: https://docs.objectbox.io/advanced/data-model-updates#changing-property-types

Comment: `You will have to take care of this yourself, e.g. by keeping the old property and adding some migration logic.` but how? None of the methods described there gives any hint on how to do it without losing old data

Answer (score 1):

@Farid a manual migration could look somewhat like this:

1. add a new field to the model, with the new type you want to use, e.g. `newField`
2. add code that updates all objects, reading `oldField` and writing the appropriate value to `newField`
3. remove `oldField` from the model, now that all the data is migrated
4. optionally, you can [follow the docs on how to rename](https://docs.objectbox.io/advanced/data-model-updates#renaming-entities-and-properties) `newField` to anything you want

Comment: What I want to do is type migration that will keep previous data which, apparently, is not supported in ObjectBox mentioned in this issue: https://github.com/objectbox/objectbox-java/issues/971. "optionally, you can follow the docs on how to rename newField to anything you want" I want to do *type-migration* not *property-renaming*